# What is js validation for multiple file upload example: name="files[]"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

it is js is not working help me

```
<input id="files" type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
```

my js is...

```
$("#GallaryForm").validate({

    rules:
    {
        event_id:
        {
            required: true,
        },
        files:
        {
            required: true,
        },



    },
    messages:
    {
        event_id:
        {
            required: 'Please Select Event .',

        },
        files:
        {
            required: 'Please Upload Image or Video.',
        },

    },
});
```

Help me
on files 
validation 
it is not
working...

Comment: Great question but the amount of indentation is ridiculous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name of the field should be in single quote.

```
 'files[]':
    {
         required: true,
    }
```

and

```
 'files[]':
    {
        required: 'Please Upload Image or Video.'
    }
```

Your code should look like

```
$("#GallaryForm").validate({
    rules: {
        event_id: {
            required: true, // <-- this comma is not required
        },
        'files[]': {
            required: true, // <-- this comma is not required
        },   // <-- this comma is not required
    },
    messages: {
        event_id: {
            required: 'Please Select Event .', // <-- this comma is not required
        },
        'files[]': {
            required: 'Please Upload Image or Video.', // <-- this comma is not required
        }, // <-- this comma is not required
    }, // <-- this comma is not required
});
```

Comment: Thanks  for  'files[]':

Answer (score 0):

You should take the name of the element in a single quote to apply rules and messages in jquery validation

```
$("#GallaryForm").validate({
    rules: {
        event_id: {
            required: true,
        },
        'files[]': {
            required: true,
        },
    },
    messages: {
        event_id: {
            required: 'Please Select Event .',
        },
        'files[]': {
            required: 'Please Upload Image or Video.',
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for 'files[]':